# Godot: Using an argument's methods as kwarg

Tags: scripting, godot

[image: Note node_link]

I downloaded and tried out the [Rakugo](https://github.com/jebedaia360/Rakugo) addon out of the box and I ran into this problem:

'Parser Error: Identifier 'node' is not declared in current scope'

If you look you can see that node is an argument variable and the kwarg is meant to be a method (name) of that arg.

It seems that gdscript does not allow this.

My question is, 'how do I fix this or work around it?'

Comment: You could default node_id to null in the parameter list, and then use an if statement within the function to set it if it's not set.

Comment: @flesk I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: @flesk That worked out well! I did run into another unrelated problem though.

Comment: Glad it worked out. :)